# convert the output into an list

Tags: c#, xml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace SampleProgram1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = @"<people> 
<person><name>kumar</name><school>fes</school><parent>All</parent></person> 
<person><name>manju</name><school>fes</school><parent>kumar</parent></person> 
<person><name>anu</name><school>frank</school><parent>kumar</parent></person> 
<person><name>anitha</name><school>jss</school><parent>All</parent></person> 
<person><name>rohit</name><school>frank</school><parent>manju</parent></person> 
<person><name>anill</name><school>vijaya</school><parent>manju</parent></person> 
<person><name>vani</name><school>jss</school><parent>kumar</parent></person> 
<person><name>soumya</name><school>jss</school><parent>kumar</parent></person> 
<person><name>madhu</name><school>jss</school><parent>rohit</parent></person> 
<person><name>shiva</name><school>jss</school><parent>rohit</parent></person> 
<person><name>vanitha</name><school>jss</school><parent>anitha</parent></person> 
<person><name>anu</name><school>jss</school><parent>anitha</parent></person> 
</people>";

            XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var people = (from person in document.Descendants("person")
                          select new Person
                          {
                              Name = (string)person.Element("name"),
                              School = (string)person.Element("school"),
                              Parent = (string)person.Element("parent")
                          }).ToList();

            var parents = people.Where(p => p.Parent == "All");

            Action<Person> findChildren = null;
            findChildren = person =>
            {
                List<Person> children = people.Where(p => p.Parent == person.Name).ToList();
                person.Children = children;
                foreach (Person p in children)
                    findChildren(p);
            };

            foreach (Person parent in parents)
            {
                findChildren(parent);
            }


            Action<Person, int> showChildren = null;
            showChildren = (person, tabs) =>
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(new string('\t', tabs) + person.Name);

                if (person.Children != null)
                {
                    foreach (Person p in person.Children)
                        showChildren(p, tabs + 1);
                }
            };

            foreach (Person parent in parents)
            {
                showChildren(parent, 0);
            }
           // Console.Read();
        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string School { get; set; }
        public string Parent { get; set; }
        public List<Person> Children { get; set; }
    } 

}
```

this my program where i **need to  put the  output into a list** and then bind the list into a `gridview`

Can any one help me out in syntax achieving this one?  I am using c# 3.5.

Once  i create an hierarchy  then need  to  format the data like this based on hierarchy

ex:

```
namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public class SampleProjectData
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<Product> GetSampleData()
        {
            DateTime dtS = DateTime.Now;


            ObservableCollection<Product> teams = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
            teams.Add(new Product() { PDName = "Product1", OverallStartTime = dtS, OverallEndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(3),  });


            Project emp = new Project() { PName = "Project1", OverallStartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(1), OverallEndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(6)  };
            emp.Tasks.Add(new Task() { StartTime = dtS, EndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(2), TaskName = "John's Task 3" });
            emp.Tasks.Add(new Task() { StartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(3), EndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(4), TaskName = "John's Task 2" });
            teams[0].Projects.Add(emp);


            emp = new Project() { PName = "Project2", OverallStartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(1.5), OverallEndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(5.5) };
            emp.Tasks.Add(new Task() { StartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(1), EndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(4), TaskName = "Victor's Task" });
            teams[0].Projects.Add(emp);

            emp = new Project() { PName = "Project3", OverallStartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(2), OverallEndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(5) };
            emp.Tasks.Add(new Task() { StartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(1), EndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(4), TaskName = "Jason's Task 1" });
            emp.Tasks.Add(new Task() { StartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(7), EndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(9), TaskName = "Jason's Task 2" });
            teams[0].Projects.Add(emp);

            teams.Add(new Product() { PDName = "Product2", OverallStartTime = dtS, OverallEndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(3) });

            emp = new Project() { PName = "Project4", OverallStartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(0.5), OverallEndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(3.5) };
            emp.Tasks.Add(new Task() { StartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(1.5), EndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(4), TaskName = "Vicky's Task" });
            teams[1].Projects.Add(emp);

            emp = new Project() { PName = "Project5", OverallStartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(2), OverallEndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(6) };
            emp.Tasks.Add(new Task() { StartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(2.2), EndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(3.8), TaskName = "Oleg's Task 1" });
            emp.Tasks.Add(new Task() { StartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(5), EndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(6), TaskName = "Oleg's Task 2" });
            emp.Tasks.Add(new Task() { StartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(8), EndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(9.6), TaskName = "Oleg's Task 3" });
            teams[1].Projects.Add(emp);

            emp = new Project() { PName = "Project6", OverallStartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(2.5), OverallEndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(4.5) };
            emp.Tasks.Add(new Task() { StartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(0.8), EndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(2), TaskName = "Kim's Task" });
            teams[1].Projects.Add(emp);


            teams.Add(new Product() { PDName = "Product3", OverallStartTime = dtS, OverallEndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(3) });

            emp = new Project() { PName = "Project7", OverallStartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(5), OverallEndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(7.5) };
            emp.Tasks.Add(new Task() { StartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(1.5), EndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(4), TaskName = "Balaji's Task 1" });
            emp.Tasks.Add(new Task() { StartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(5), EndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(8), TaskName = "Balaji's Task 2" });
            teams[2].Projects.Add(emp);

            emp = new Project() { PName = "Project8", OverallStartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(3), OverallEndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(6.3) };
            emp.Tasks.Add(new Task() { StartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(1.75), EndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(2.25), TaskName = "Li's Task" });
            teams[2].Projects.Add(emp);

            emp = new Project() { PName = "Project9", OverallStartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(2), OverallEndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(6) };
            emp.Tasks.Add(new Task() { StartTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(2), EndTime = dtS + TimeSpan.FromDays(3), TaskName = "Stacy's Task" });
            teams[2].Projects.Add(emp);

            return teams;
        }
    }
    public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Product()
        {
            this.Projects = new ObservableCollection<Project>();
        }
        public string PDName { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        private DateTime _st;
        public DateTime OverallStartTime
        {
            get { return _st; }
            set
            {
                if (this._st != value)
                {
                    TimeSpan dur = this._et - this._st;
                    this._st = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("OverallStartTime");
                    this.OverallEndTime = value + dur;
                }
            }
        }
        private DateTime _et;
        public DateTime OverallEndTime
        {
            get { return _et; }
            set
            {
                if (this._et != value)
                {
                    this._et = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("OverallEndTime");
                }
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }
    public class Project : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Project() { this.Tasks = new ObservableCollection<Task>(); }
        public string PName { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
        DateTime _st;
        public DateTime OverallStartTime
        {
            get { return _st; }
            set
            {
                if (this._st != value)
                {
                    TimeSpan dur = this._et - this._st;
                    this._st = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("OverallStartTime");
                    this.OverallEndTime = value + dur;
                }
            }
        }
        DateTime _et;
        public DateTime OverallEndTime
        {
            get { return _et; }
            set
            {
                if (this._et != value)
                {
                    this._et = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("OverallEndTime");
                }
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }
    public class Task : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string TaskName { get; set; }
        DateTime _st;
        public DateTime StartTime
        {
            get { return _st; }
            set
            {
                if (this._st != value)
                {
                    TimeSpan dur = this._et - this._st;
                    this._st = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("StartTime");
                    this.EndTime = value + dur;
                }
            }
        }
        private DateTime _et;
        public DateTime EndTime
        {
            get { return _et; }
            set
            {
                if (this._et != value)
                {
                    this._et = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("EndTime");
                }
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: what output? You have a slew of different lists and variables - which one do you mean??? Do you mean your `parents` collection? Or what else??

Comment: based on the on the hierarchy created i need  to create an list

Comment: A list of what object? Tell me the object which you are trying to put into a list and I can code it up for you, but you're not being too clear...

Comment: @Vijay, I think happysmile wants the entire hierarchy displayed in a grid, not just one of the lists.